# Need help to understand one-line c code output

Tags: c

Please consider the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2}, 
                       {2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0} };
    printf("%u, %u, %u, %u\n", a, *a, **a, ***a);
    return 0;
}
```

If I am not wrong `a` points to the position where array begins.So why `a ,*a ,**a` all three give same location?

Comment: Note: your code invokes **undefined behaviour** (asking `printf` to interpret pointer types with `%u`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct

A pointer to a pointer is a variable, like any other variable, but that holds the address of a variable. That variable just happens to be a pointer.

A reference to this 2D array will have type `(a*)* = a**`, and is hence a pointer to a pointer.

**On a side note:-** As Oli Charlesworth commented your code is invoking an undefined behavior as you are using %u to interpret pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer variable in C has two attributes: the address, and the type.  When you print a pointer with the `%u` format code in `printf()`, you only get the address.  (As others have noted on this page, you shouldn't really use `%u` for this.  You should use `%p` if it is available for your `printf()`.)

This is a legal expression:

```
a[0][0][0]
```

This indexes `a` three times.  If `a` had type "pointer to integer" you could only index it one time; it's actually a three-times-indirect pointer.  (If you had declared it as `int ***a;` it would simply be a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an integer; because you declared it as a fixed-size array, the C compiler knows the size of the array pointed to by `a`.)

You can do this:

```
int *p = a[0][0];
```

Indexing `a` twice gives a result that is of type pointer-to-int.

But you can't do this without a cast:

```
int **p = a[0];
```

This is because the C compiler knows that if you index `a[0]`, it needs to multiply the index by `4*sizeof(int)` to find the correct integer address, because this is a fixed-size array and the innermost array size is 4.  If you do use a cast and force `a[0]` into the variable `p`, now if you index `p` the C compiler will assume that the result points to a pointer.  It won't, so you can't really use `p` in a useful way.